# Salesforce close case tab event catch

Tags: javascript, salesforce, dom-events

Is there a way to listen when user closed tab event ?
I want to add a listener in a canvas app and execute some code when casetab was closed.

Comment: Have you tried anything to do that?

Comment: I didn't find any method in the "Methods for Primary Tabs and Subtabs" documentation